# how to access array returned by google map api v3's getarray()

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am a newbie at using google map api v3 . I used

> paths=polygon.getPath().getArray();

to fetch arrays of Coordinates from the polygon I just draw . Now how can I access each elements of paths when I send this array to another function. How can I access each lat and Lon from this array ? Please help

Comment: Fire up the console (Firebug, Dragonfly, ...) and have a look at `console.log(paths)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So paths is an array of coordinates?

Loop over the array like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {

}
```

Within that `for` statement, you can then get the individual lat and lng values like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
  lat = paths[i].lat();
  lng = paths[i].lng();
}
```